# How to fix SSH console encoding error

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, console

I'm not sure if encoding is the word but I just deployed a plain instance of Ubuntu 10.04 in Amazon's EC2

I log in to the server from a Windows PC with PUTTY and here is the output of a `tree` command:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting utf-8 encoding in PUTTY Window -> Translation -> Remote Character Set did the trick

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027403/vim-show-strange-characters-over-putty/5027543#5027543